# Autowiring by constructor in Spring creating more objects

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am creating a demo to understand that how can i inject a prototype bean into a singleton bean by using constructor autowiring. Here is my code
My First bean is

```
public class IndependentBean {
    private String independentName;
    public IndependentBean()
    {
        System.out.println("Independent called");
    }

    public String getIndependentName() {
        return independentName;
    }

    public void setIndependentName(String independentName) {
        this.independentName = independentName;
    }
}
```

Now I am creating an independent bean

package com.sample.beans;

```
public abstract class DependentBean {
    private IndependentBean d1;
    private IndependentBean d2;
    public DependentBean()
    {
        System.out.println("Default Constructor for dependent");
    }
    public IndependentBean getD1() {
        return d1;
    }

    public void setD1(IndependentBean d1) {
        System.out.println("Setting d1");
        this.d1 = d1;
    }

    public IndependentBean getD2() {
        return d2;
    }

    public void setD2(IndependentBean d2) {
        System.out.println("Setting d2");
        this.d2 = d2;
    }

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public DependentBean(IndependentBean d1) {
        System.out.println("With 1");
        this.d1 = d1;
    }

    public DependentBean(IndependentBean d1, IndependentBean d2) {
        this.d1 = d1;
        this.d2 = d2;
        System.out.println("With 2");
    }
 public abstract IndependentBean getIndependent();
}
```

Here is my *context.xml*:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd">
        <bean class="com.sample.beans.IndependentBean" id="firstIn" scope="prototype">
            <property name="independentName" value="firstIndependent" />
        </bean>

        <bean class="com.sample.beans.DependentBean" id="autowireByConstructor"
            autowire="constructor">
  <lookup-method name="getIndependent" bean="firstIn" />
            </bean>
    </beans>
```

Here is my main class

```
package com.sample.beans;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "classpath:context.xml");
        ctx.getBean("autowireByConstructor");
        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

According toSpring spec I know that when i am working with autowiring with constructor the constructor with satisfying most dependencies will be called.
However in this case the constructor of independent bean should be call 2 times.but in my case the constructor is called 4 times. I am not getting this clearly.Please help me to understand this ?

Here is the output of the code:

> Independent called
>   Independent called
>   Independent called
>   Independent called
>   With 2

Please help me to understand this behaviour.

Comment: I am using Spring 4.1.5 in this code

Comment: Above Dependent is an abstract class and can't be initialized. Tried with the scenario Though,  it calls the constructor of Independent two times but throws an error in last due to abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of this question in Spring Docs.

While we use look-up method injection, Spring uses cglib proxies to fulfill the requirement.When Spring uses cglib proxies the constructor of the target bean called two time.
Hence here in my case Since two proxies of Independent bean will be created and constructor will be called 4 times.